# How do I limit user input to certain number of strings?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
echo "Leonel Messi - LM, Harry Kane - HK, Neymar Junior - NJ, Keiran Trippier - KT"
echo "Enter 3 player codes:"
read p1 p2 p3
players=($p1 $p2 $p3)
        echo Empty field
    if [[ ${p[@]} -gt 3 ]]
    then
        echo More than 3 argument
    fi
```

I've tried this but it does not seem to do anything. Bash newbie here. I was looking to restrict user input to only three inputs and show error in case more than 3 inputs are entered.

Comment: `"${#p[@]}"` should do the trick. Also quote them variables `"$p1"` not `$p1` and so on.

Comment: no it still doesnot work

Comment: Right it should be `"${#players[@]}"` not `"${#p[@]}"`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest:

```
while (( 3 != ${#p[@]} )) # while 3 is not the number of elements in array p
do read -a p -p "Enter three (3) player codes: " # read elements into array p
done
```

Embellish for pretty as you like.